# Extract Uppercase Words on Excel

Tags: excel, formula, uppercase

I have 167 cells, and each cell a string of text, where each cell has a word that's all uppercase and I need to copy only that word to a new cell.
I've tried the EXACT formula, but it only identifies if the text has an uppercase word and returns with a "true" or "false".

The result should be:

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| The quick brown fox JUMPS over the lazy dog | JUMPS |

Comment: Please provide an example and expected results.

Comment: @Jbowman, I've edited the file with an example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function grabber(s As String) As String
    grabber = ""
    arry = Split(s, " ")
    For Each a In arry
        If a = UCase(a) Then
            grabber = a
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

It will extract the **first** uppercase word in the cell.

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

*(this code can easily be modified to extract all the uppercase words from a sentence)*

Comment: although that works, sometimes this happens:[https://imgur.com/TS3Gipb](https://imgur.com/TS3Gipb)
Since the first letter is in uppercase.

Comment: @Caracks  If the code gives bad results, post a sample of how it fails and we can fix it.

Comment: @Caracks  I can't follow your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to extract the uppercase words. This can be deployed as an UDF in the sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim tests(), i As Long
    tests = Array("The lazy LAD was sorry for the debacle", "She wept as her FLAXEN hair tumbled down the parapet")

    For i = LBound(tests) To UBound(tests)
        Debug.Print GetString(tests(i))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Z]+\b"
        If .TEST(inputString) Then
            If len(.Execute(inputString)(0)) > 1 Then
                GetString = .Execute(inputString)(0)
                Exit Function
            End If     
        End If
        GetString = vbNullString
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/6Zi9NU/1).

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]+`

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`A-Z` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

---

**In sheet:**

[image]

Comment: That's what I need! However, when a capital letter by itself it's on the sentence, it filters said letter. As such: https://regex101.com/r/TXBD49/1/

Comment: Yup. It is all uppercase and a single word which is what the regex is looking for. 
I also tell it to only return the first match. I could have it cycle all matches and only return greater than one letter words or exclude certain words .........The only way to differentiate this would be if there are certain words that must be ignored  or if words must be a certain length.

Comment: What are your rules in this case?

Comment: Only to select words, exclude single letters